# Why doesn't saving queryset element at index work in django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to save an object at a particular index of my queryset but it doesn't seem to work.

I have a model called Customer and I wish to change a field called first_name from None to something, say 'aa' and I want to do this for index 0.

## code 1

```
customers = Customer.objects.filter(first_name=None)
customers[0].first_name = 'aa'
customers[0].save()
```

## code 2

```
customers = Customer.objects.filter(first_name=None)
customer = customers[0]
customer.first_name = 'aa'
customer.save()
```

Code 1 doesn't work but Code 2 works. Why doesn't the code 1 work?

Comment: Hint: Is `customers[0] is customers[0]` true or false? How about `customer is customer`?

Comment: How are you verifying whether the object has been saved?

Comment: @solarissmoke: Am checking customer[0].__dict__ after re-fetching the queryset after saving...

Comment: And how are you re-fetching the queryset? I feel like you're most likely fetching cached results.

Answer (score 0):

The following query return multiple queryset:

```
customers = Customer.objects.filter(first_name=None)
```

When you use

```
customers[0].first_name = 'aa'
```

You instruct to django to set `first_name` property with value `aaa` in first `customers` (first customer you refered by [0]).

When you use

```
customer = customers[0]
```

That means you assign customers first objects to `customer` so you can assign a value to objects.

Comment: Thanks for your response but this is not the answer I am looking for. I am asking why customer[0].save() doesn't save the instance while customer.save() does.